# HttpCookie.Path with url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, path

I am using cookies for the first time in ASP NET c# and I would like to know if someone could clarify if it is possible to specify in the "Path" property of a HttpCookie class, a url with parameters, for example: http://192.168.17.20/moduleInputDecoder.aspx?nIDEngine=0. Thanks in advance.